# Android: HttpPost not work

Tags: java, php, android, json, post

Hi guy's (sorry for my english error :P ) i have a problem, I'm trying to post a variable (id_art) to a php page, the problem is that I can't understand if the variable is not sent properly, or if I read it wrong php side.

JAVA CODE:

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(myurl);
 StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
 String json, result = "";

//Build jsonObject
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.accumulate("id_articolo", id_art);
//Convert JSONObject to JSON to String
json = jsonObject.toString();
//Set json to StringEntity
StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
//Set httpPost Entity
httpPost.setEntity(se);
//Set some headers to inform server about the type of the content   
httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
//Execute POST request to the given URL
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
//Receive response as inputStream
StatusLine statusLine = httpResponse.getStatusLine();
int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
//Convert input stream to string
if (statusCode == 200){     
   HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
   InputStream content = entity.getContent();
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
   String line="";

   while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      builder.append(line);
      result = builder.toString();
   }
     System.out.println("DEBUG"+" "+result);
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php
include_once('configurazione.php');
header("Content-Type: application/json");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$value = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST),true);
var_dump($value);
?>
```

result is NULL... Why ????

Tnks 4 help

**EDIT 1**

I try to edit my php code replacing

this : json_decode(stripslashes($_POST),true);

with: $value = json_decode($_POST);

But the result is the same.. NULL

**EDIT 2**
I try to replace

in .JAVA

httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(yourJson.toString(),"UTF-8"));

in .PHP
$value = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
echo $value ;

but result is NULL

Comment: $_POST is array that's why. stripslashes is used for string

Comment: phpinfo() is your friend when you need to know what the server is receiving. It's overkill, but it will show you if and where your JSON is getting sent.

Comment: I try to edit my php code replacing 

this : json_decode(stripslashes($_POST),true); 

with: $value = json_decode($_POST); 

But the result is the same.. NULL

Comment: my 1st answer is working?

Comment: I try all answer but no one works... I don't understand what's wrong !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in .JAVA

```
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(yourJson.toString(),"UTF-8"));
```

in .PHP

```
$value = file_get_contents('php://input');
var_dump(json_decode($value , true));
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this
in .JAVA

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", yourJson.toString()));  
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

in .PHP

```
$value = $_POST['json'];
var_dump(json_decode($value , true));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you cannot simply send `StringEntity`, because POST parameters are expected to be key=>value pairs. That means you need to give a name to your parameter, let's say `json`.

Then you can do this:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
// here you can set up the data

HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", jsonObject.toString()));
// here you can add more POST data using nameValuePairs.add()

httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

On the PHP side, you'll just do

```
$value = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);
var_dump($value);
```